# Plugin [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '2.8'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Tags: gradle, plugins, sonarqube, version, jcenter

Good day,

The following is part of my code in `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
           url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
  dependencies {
   classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.8"
  }
}

plugins {
  //id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.6.2'
  id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.8'
}

apply plugin: 'nebula.nebula-release'

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"

apply from: "gradle/locations.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/buildEnvironment.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/project.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/versions.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/jacoco.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/sonarqube.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/testing.gradle"
```

When i run gradle command, it will hit the following error:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'org.sonarqube', version: '2.8'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.sonarqube:org.sonarqube.gradle.plugin:2.8')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

However, if I change the `id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.8'` in my build.gradle to `id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.6.2'`, it will build success.

May I know what mistake I make?

** I am very new to gradle **

Answer (score 2):

Adding dependency manually and applying it is not recommended (read [Legacy Plugin Application](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:old_plugin_application)). [Plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) is a recommended way. Definitely you shouldn't use both at the same time.

Your fragment should be changed to:

```
plugins {
  id 'nebula.nebula-release' version '4.0.1'
  id 'org.sonarqube' version '2.8'
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
  mavenCentral()
}

apply from: "gradle/locations.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/buildEnvironment.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/project.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/versions.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/jacoco.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/sonarqube.gradle"
apply from: "gradle/testing.gradle"
```

I don't know which version of the [nebula.nebula-release](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/nebula.nebula-release) plugin you use, so I took the latest.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. In my case, I was running Gradle offline so it was not able to download the plugin.